# Azure Sql DataWarehouse - How do I get the table name and columns of all tables in tempdb

Tags: azure-synapse

I can't access tempdb from a database other than master.

When I run the following query:

```
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
```

I receive this error:

```
Invalid object name 'tempdb.pdw.tables'
```

It only works when queried from master database.

Is there any internal view or non-documented way to go around this?